# MVC Core WEBApi dynamic connection string

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I have two MVC Core project, one for the Context and one for the WebApi.
In WebAPI methods I need to query a different database based on a parameter passed to the method itself.

How can I configure the connection string of the Context based on the parameter?

Thank you.

Comment: Did both database have same schema ?

Comment: Yes. All databases have the same schema. Thank you

Comment: which version of visual studio you used ? 2015 or 2017 ?

Comment: VS 2017. Thank you :)